# Angular ignores file-loader in AOT build

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-aot, angular-aot, webpack-loader

I'm currently trying to build a documentation website in Angular. Docs will be written in markdown and displayed through the ngx-markdown plugin. Everything works fine on a JIT build, but an AOT build always removes the markdown files.

This is how I import the file:

```
import usageNavbar from '!!raw-loader!./content/usage-navbar.md';

[...]
{
  title: 'Installation',
  text: usageNavbar
}
[...]
```

I've tried using just the raw-loader plugin, but this will just load *null* on AOT:

```
{title: "Installation", text: null}
```

Then I've tried to setup webpacks file-loader which will output *void 0* when building AOT:

```
{title: "Installation", text: void 0}
```

But JIT looks like this:

```
{
  title: 'Installation',
  text: _raw_loader_content_usage_navbar_md__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["default"]
}
```

and contains this folder in its dist:
[image: dist folder containing /docs]

There are no error messages or anything it just completely removes any evidence of a markdown file ever existing.

I think [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/9de389fb770568919d6f2465cc155e0835926eaf/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/common.ts#L255) is the webpack config Angular uses, but there is nothing that would indicate this happening.
There is also [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13967) issue which wasn't very helpful.

This is the webpack config I am using with the [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) plugin:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.md$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: `[name][hash].[ext]`,
          outputPath: 'docs/',
          emitFile: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

angular.json:

```
[...]
"customWebpackConfig": {
  "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
  "mergeStrategies": {
    "module.rules": "prepend"
  }
}
[...]
```

I'm using Angular 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually the way I passed the data.

I was passing it through a .forRoot()-method which set a token to the value. Angular didn't recognise it (i think), and dropped it upon compilation.

I fixed it by setting the token directly.